# Cosmos DB maximum file size limit 1.5MB

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to update a json file in an azure cosmos database using pymongo's update_one/update_many methods.
I'm get an error code 17419 (Resulting document after update is larger than *x*)
According to the [azure cosmos db documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits), the file size limit is **2MB**, but my file is now **1.498MB** and the data i'm trying to insert is nowhere near 0.5MB (it's only **49.5kB**) and **1.5 + 0.049 < 2** for as far as I know...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits),2 mb limitation is directed against request,not only for file.

[image]

CRUD request contains not only file data, but also headers and so on. So,i'm afraid that your update request is over 2 mb,though your file data is below 2 mb. You could try to catch the size of your request with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool so that you could troubleshooting the cause of it.